# How to upload image data to server with specific file name?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, post, file-upload

**Xcode Source Code**

```
NSString *path = [self pathOfCharacterFolder];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[self fileNamesOfCharacters] objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"http://temp-sample-page/uploadfile.html";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
```

Please Check Below Source Code...

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/html;charset=UTF-8; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"123456700.png\"rn"] 
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: multipart/form-datarnrn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What is wrong? (html page works fine)

**Sample page html code**

```
<html>

<head>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<title>Upload Example</title>

<script>
    function validate() {
        var image =document.getElementById("image").value;
        if(image!=''){
            var checkimg = image.toLowerCase();
            if (!checkimg.match(/(\.jpg|\.png|\.JPG|\.PNG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/)){
                alert("Please enter Image File Extensions .jpg,.png,.jpeg");
                document.getElementById("image").focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="/uploadfile.html" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();">

    <fieldset><legend>Upload File</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="fileData" id="image" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br />
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No explanation, a huge code block, then enjoy your anwser...

Comment: @Martin Sorry, but I am not good at English... I am very hard to write long question in English.

Comment: what happens? any log/response/error? what is imageData?

Comment: also make sure rn is not anything in it you should use \r\n for your purpose.

Comment: @Ravin In my opinion, header or body settings are wrong. I copied and pasted some source code... and edit some part of code.

Comment: @Ravin app runs withouht error. but uploading does not worked.

Comment: please try with code I provided in answer and let me know if it works?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8296/discussion-between-ravin-and-changuz)

Comment: Hi... have you tried with the updated code I provided in answer. Also have some variable to hold the value of Error.

Comment: If issue still persists than change the connection to asynchronous one and try. Also use error variable to have error reference if any.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :(rn is changed to : \r\n) carriage return and new line character.

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"123456700.png\"\r\n"] 
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

**Upadted Code:**

also I am not sure about your imageData. How you create it?

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=picture; filename=\"123456700.png\"\r\n"] 
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"123456700.png\"

Comment: form-data, image are correct value? I just write down after see soem sample codes.

Comment: Content-Disposition: form-data; name=picture; filename=\"123456700.png\"\r\n

Comment: Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n

Comment: NSData has no problem I checked.

Comment: please check last one, setting header... Thanks. You are very kind.

Comment: Is problem still there? Please updated your latest code in question so that we can make changes if needed. Are you populating error variable and logging it?